# ReadProcessMemory don't work

Tags: c#, memory

I have a problem with the `ReadProcessMemory` method in C#. It worked properly when I implemented it. After that I closed Visual Studio 15 and then when I reopened VS it didn't work.

It always returns 0 and doesn't change the buffer value. I tested it by editing one bit from the buffer. `ReadProcessMemory` didn't change the buffer.
I read a lot of articles about this method but I haven't found a solution.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

public static byte[] ReadBytes(IntPtr Handle, Int64 Address, uint BytesToRead)
{
    IntPtr bytesRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BytesToRead];
    ReadProcessMemory(Handle, new IntPtr(Address), buffer, BytesToRead, out bytesRead);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of "Address" parameter?

Comment: For example 0x6CE120 + 0x10 offset but it has worked with this value. It's so strange... I get this value from cheatengine. This value don't change every rexecute process bacause it is static. I have checked it.

Comment: Based on my old knowledge, the address is not bound to the process, but to the system area. It may or may not crash depending on how the "Address" is allocated. The address might be greater than 0x80000000 if it is in the process space.

Comment: But it has worked with this adress and read proper value. Now it doesn't.

Comment: Sometimes it may work but sometimes not with the address. The correct user space address boundary is 0x80000000. Reading values after boundary will be safe. Otherwise it may trigger access violation depending on the memory status.

Comment: But I'm not using system area. I have base adress (process adress) + 0x6CE120 + 0x10 (offset).

<i>
Process[] Tibia = Process.GetProcessesByName("Tibia");
            IntPtr Handle = Tibia[0].Handle;
            UInt32 Base = (UInt32)Tibia[0].MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
</i>